# LIBGDX : FirstPersonCameraController and TextButton working together

Tags: java, libgdx

I am writing a new 3D game and using the FirstPersonCameraController (subclassed) which works well.  I then detect if I am on mobile and add some TextButton to the stage.  These appear but can't be pressed?

```
public ControlsController(Camera camera, GameRenderScreen gameRenderScreen, Stage stage) {
        super(camera);
        this.gameRenderScreen = gameRenderScreen;

        // create control
        if (Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.Android || Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.iOS)
        {
            forwardButton = new TextButton("Forward", Gui.getSkin());
            forwardButton.setBounds(width() - 130,  130, 80, 50);
            stage.addActor(forwardButton);

            leftButton = new TextButton("Left", Gui.getSkin());
            leftButton.setBounds(width() - 170,  70, 70, 50);
            stage.addActor(leftButton);

            rightButton = new TextButton("Right", Gui.getSkin());
            rightButton.setBounds(width() - 80,  70, 70, 50);
            stage.addActor(rightButton);

            backwardButton = new TextButton("Backward", Gui.getSkin());
            backwardButton.setBounds(width() - 130,  10, 80, 50);
            stage.addActor(backwardButton);
        }

        InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

    }
```

// this is called via the main render loop

```
public void updateControls(){

        if (Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.Android || Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.iOS) {

            if (forwardButton.isPressed()) {
                keyDown(Input.Keys.W);
            }

            if (backwardButton.isPressed()) {
                keyDown(Input.Keys.S);
            }

            if (leftButton.isPressed()) {
                keyDown(Input.Keys.A);
            }

            if (rightButton.isPressed()) {
                keyDown(Input.Keys.D);
            }
        }

    }
```

// update camera

```
    public void update(){

            fps.update();
            fps.updateControls();
            camera.position.set(camera.position.x, 0.0f, camera.position.z); 
        }
```

// Update rendering loop

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update();

        Gdx.gl20.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        //TODO do we need all of these?
        //Do all your basic OpenGL ES setup to start the screen render.
        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl20.glCullFace(GL20.GL_BACK);
        Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // Like spriteBatch, just with models!  pass in the box Instance and the environment
        modelBatch.begin(camera);

        Skybox.update(camera.position);
        modelBatch.render(Skybox.modelInstance);

        for (int i = 0; i < boxInstance.size; i ++ ) {
            modelBatch.render(boxInstance.get(i));
        }

        modelBatch.end();

        //TODO Whats this for
        stage.getViewport().update(width(), height(), true);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();

        drawFPS();
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `stage.act()` in your render loop?

Comment: Yes (had to check :) ), I posted up my rendering loop to :)

Comment: What does the debugger say if you add a breakpoint in `Stage.touchDown()`?

Answer (score 0):

I always like to post a answer incase it helps others.

I had set Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(fpsController) after I had set up all the buttons which I believe overwrote the original Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);